# How can I add a resource to a silverlight custom control?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, converters

I am trying to trim the selected value of a silverlight custom control combobox. I have found that using the IValueConverter class should be the way to go. So I create this in my library

```
public class StringTrimmer : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString().Trim();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

this is the xaml for the combobox

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightControlLibrary.SilverlightComboBoxControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Height="25" Width="122">
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
          Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="ModuleIDFilterCB" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Screen.LicenseModuleIDs, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="LicenseModuleName"      
          SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.bufferProp, Converter={StaticResource StringTrimmer},Mode=TwoWay}"
          />
</UserControl>
```

Except that the resource "StringTrimmer" for the SelectedItem can't be resolved. I tried adding this reference to the xaml and it still didnt work.

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SilverlightControlLibrary"
```

EDIT: I also tried this

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SilverlightControlLibrary"
```

along with

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.bufferProp, Converter= {StaticResource custom:StringTrimmer}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

to no avail..

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx is what microsof has to say about XAML namespaces

and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx is for the IValueConverter

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add static resource (`UserControl.Resources` section) to reference your converter e.g.:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="SilverlightControlLibrary.SilverlightComboBoxControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Height="25" 
    Width="122"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SilverlightControlLibrary">

<UserControl.Resources>
   <custom:StringTrimmer x:Key="StringTrimmer" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox Height="23" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="120"
          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
          Name="ModuleIDFilterCB" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Screen.LicenseModuleIDs, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="LicenseModuleName"      
          SelectedItem="{Binding Screen.bufferProp, Converter={StaticResource StringTrimmer}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

For XAML reference you can use any name in `x:Key` attribute, not only "StringTrimmer".